# How to define case switch to check if the case variable includes specific strings by using regex?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a Jenkins pipeline as a code in order to build an Android application.

The job is configured as "GitHub Organization" which means that Jenkins is scanning the given repository, adds each branch as a job and starts a job run whenever a git commit takes place.

```
switch(BRANCH_NAME) {
    case "develop":
        BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
        BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    case "master":
        BUILDFLAV = "Production"
        BUILDTYPE = "Release"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    case "release_candidate":
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    case "hotfix":
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    case "jenkins-pipeline":
        BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
        BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    case "feature/upload_to_hockeyapp":
        BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
        BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    case "feature/notifications":
        BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
        BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        break
    default:
        println "Branch name was not set!"
        break
}
```

Some of the branches are named like so:

```
hotfix/3.0.1
release/3.2.1
```

I'd like to define a case option for these branches, something like:

```
case "^hotfix.*"
   code....
   break
```

And:

```
case "^release\/.*"
    code...
    break
```

Edit #1:
Here's the code after adding your part:

```
// Branch selection
def showRelease(BRANCH_NAME, regex) {
    def pattern = "(release|hotfix)\\/(\\d+\\.)?(\\d+\\.)?(\\*|\\d+)"
    switch(BRANCH_NAME) {
        case "develop":
            BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
            BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
        case "master":
            BUILDFLAV = "Production"
            BUILDTYPE = "Release"
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
        case "release_candidate":
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
        case "hotfix":
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
        case "jenkins-pipeline":
            BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
            BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
        case "feature/notifications":
            BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
            BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
        case ~/$regex/:
            BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
            BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            println BRANCH_NAME

            break
        default:
            println "Branch name was not set!"
            break
    }
}
```

But then, when I run the build, BRANCH_NAME is not set correctly and the next steps are unable to run because they lack the BUILDFLAV and BUILDTYPE variables.

Edit #2:
I've added the code you suggested:

```
case ~/(release|hotfix)\\/(\\d+\\.)?(\\d+\\.)?(\\*|\\d+)/:
        BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
        BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "App01-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
        println "Branch Name: ${BRANCH_NAME}"
        break
```

But now I get this error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter bitwiseNegate java.lang.Object
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:190)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:180)
```

But i'm not so familiar with regex use in Jenkins (groovy), how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it can be done in the following simple for handling *hotfix* and *releases*:

**Script:**

```
def showRelease(val, regex) {
    switch (val) {
        case ~/$regex/:
            println "branch is set: ${val}"
            break       

        default:
            println "Branch name was not set!"
            break
    }
}

def pattern = "(release|hotfix)\\/(\\d+\\.)?(\\d+\\.)?(\\*|\\d+)"
showRelease('release/1.0.1', pattern)
showRelease('release/2.2.3', pattern)
showRelease('release.3.x', pattern)
showRelease('hotfix/3.0.2', pattern)
```

And you may notice the output:

> branch is set: release/1.0.1
>   branch is set: release/2.2.3
>   **Branch name was not set!**
>   branch is set: hotfix/3.0.2

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comment, adding fixed pattern snippet:

```
switch(BRANCH_NAME) {
        case ~/(release|hotfix)\/(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)/:
            BUILDFLAV = "Staging"
            BUILDTYPE = "Debug"
            ARTIFACT_NAME = "AutoCAD360-${BUILDFLAV.toLowerCase()}-${BUILDTYPE.toLowerCase()}.apk"
            break
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfect in a Groovy IDE but how can I add it to my code? I need the BRANCH_NAME variable to hold the branch name even if it's release/hotfix.

Comment: In the example shown above, `val` is the variable and user passes different values (i.e, release or hotfix in your case) in different times. How are you calling your method?

Comment: Please check Edit #1

Comment: Also, the user doesn't pass anything, Jenkins is scanning the GitHub organization, and starts running jobs based on branch name.

Comment: `user does not pass anything` - Are you referring to `pattern` argument? That was an example to demonstrate any pattern can be passed. If you do not wish, then you can directly have fixed value that was given there in the sample.

Comment: I want that, when the build is triggered with a branch which is called for example hotfix/6.6.6 , the case switch will catch that branch name, and set it in the BRANCH_NAME variable

Comment: @ItaiGanot, I have added additional sample, please see if that helps.

Comment: I am sorry. Don't have much idea, how you may use it in jenkins. I just showed you how to use with `switch case ` with regex you wanted and the sample provided works like. Please see if this link helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116280/groovy-if-statement-with-regex-in-variable